# Google App Engine Memcache Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

Using Google App Engine **Memcache**... Can more than one user access the same key-value pair?
or in other words.. Is there a Memcache created per user or is it shared across multiple users?

Comment: GAE's memcache implementation is a distributed in-memory data cache. Meaning its not per user, and it's not persistent. Data can be evicted anytime without any notification

Comment: can u please explain more?

Comment: What do you need to understand? You basically set a value and get a value. If it does not exist in the cache, then you proceed to fetch from your datasource, or whatever the case maybe.

Comment: Hi, im trying to use memcache frm my app, but it does not seem work. Is there somthing i need to setup, set authorization variables or so?  im getting The API package 'memcache' or call 'Stats()' was not found. when trying to call stats method. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It's not shared between multiple applications if that's what you asked. Each of your instances on a single application will see a consistent view of the cache.

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/?csw=1): The cache is global and is shared across the application's frontend, backend, and all of its services and versions.

Answer (score 0):

Memcache is shared across users.  It is not a cookie, but exists in RAM on the server for all pertinent requests to access.